# How to speed up script compilation?

Tags: unity, visual-studio

Is there a way to speed up script compile time when I change something in VS then click on Unity?

It takes 15 seconds. Is this normal?

Comment: Is that on a big project, or do you experience the same on a default new project?

Comment: I opened a new HDRP demo project and it doesn't seem slow. I'm leaning more towards my horrible mesh and materials as the cause. I am using some very bad testing materials so maybe I should go optimizing those. My current work project contains some testing mesh/materials, a dozen or two scripts, several VFX, HDRP setup. But as I said my mesh and materials are quite bad. I have 8GB of RAM which I can't expand atm. So that's another problem. I'm running on Low settings during development but the game runs smooth on Ultra when I run a build.

Comment: I think you can disable auto recompile via edit/preferences (can't check atm sry), but you'd have to refresh manually then...

Comment: I disabled AutoRefresh from Prefrences and now recompile via CTRL+R, at least this way I can control when the lockdown happens. For instance when I want to look at a gameobject settings I can click on Unity then come back quickly to VS to keep coding. It's an improvement. Thanks.